# how to use Material Design control in visual basic 2008

Tags: vb.net

Is it possible to use a material design framework that is used in Visual Basic 2012 or 2015 in visual studio 2008 professional,
Material design framework which is based on .net 4 or higher
I download vc2008featurepack

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use this one: [MaterialSkin for .NET WinForms](https://github.com/IgnaceMaes/MaterialSkin)

In case you need a step by step tutorial on how to start, here you can see one: [FORMULARIO MATERIAL DESIGN - Visual Basic 2015 .NET](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=islWUCCXnX0) *(the video is in Spanish, but you can see what they do and replicate it in order to get started with your project).*

Hope it helps!